# Compare mapped objects and validate mapping dynamically

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Let's consider a dynamic mapping of an anonymous type to a predefined one:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = true);

var dest = Mapper.Map<Dest>(new {a = 42});
```

I would like to ensure all `Dest` properties were mapped. Actual values don't matter, it can be null on anything else.

This check would be similar to `Mapper.Configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` (it doesn't consider new type maps) performed before/after each map call.

Simple property-to-property Reflection comparison won't work because Automapper configuration should be taken into account (I mean all these nice features like automatic type conversion, flattening etc.). So the check should use Automapper API... or not?

P.S. I understand that it could significantly decrease the perfomance. The idea is to achieve a kind of code contract and enable it in dev configurations only. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can write unit tests for mappers (Automapper will be implementation details then) - then failed test will be your code contract in development environment.

Comment: @Fabio, how to assert without object property-to-property comparison? What should the test verify?

Comment: In tests you give anonymous object as input, then assert received result against expected output. You can compare it property by property - or use some assertion framework which provide "deep object graph" assertions.

Comment: @Fabio as I mentioned before, a simple comparison doesn't work. To resolve the problem this way, massive part of Automapper logic should be used in that hypothetic comparison framework.

Comment: Can you confirm that I understand correctly - you want create some kind of "assertion framework" which check in development environment that line `var dest = Mapper.Map<Dest>(new {a = 42});` will create instance of `Dest` with expected values configured by Automapper configurations?

Comment: @Fabio Yes, it is correct. Because Automapper does a lot of conversions inside. In simplest cases, it can convert `string Id -> int Id`, `Product.Id -> ProductId` and so on. Making these conversions manually in "assertion framework" means to re-write the Automapper =) So it is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I think unit tests, which will test your mapping logic, will do the same job as you expecting from your "framework".

Only, instead of using Automapper straight in your code, create wrapper which you will use everywhere you need and which you will test

```
public static class MapperWrapper
{
    public static Dest Map(object source)
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Dest>(source);
    }
}
```

Unit tests will provide "code contract" for `MapperWrapper.Map` method and Automapper configuration. Tests will also play a role of "safe net" for developers when they "play" with Automapper configuration.

```
// In example used
// NUnit as test framework
// FluentAssertions as assertion framework

[TestFixture]
public class MapperWrapperTests
{
    [Test]
    public void Map_ShouldReturnInstanceWithCorrectValueOfAProperty()
    {
        var expectedA = 42;
        var input = new { A = expectedA };

        var actualResult = MapperWrapper.Map(input);

        actualResult.A.Should().Be(expectedA);
    }

    // FluentAssertions framework provide "deep object graph" assertion
    [Test]
    public void Map_ShouldReturnInstanceWithCorrectValues()
    {
        var expectedResult = new Dest
        {
            Id = 42,
            Name = "Forty-Two",
            SomeAnotherType = new AnotherType { IsValid = true }
        };
        var input = new 
        { 
            Id = "42",
            Name = "Forty-Two",
            SomeAnotherType = new { IsValid = true }
        };

        var actualResult = MapperWrapper.Map(input);

        actualResult.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(expectedResult);
    }
}
```

By executing those tests on every build you will get feedback about is Automapper configuration correct.

Instead of using singleton `MapperWrapper` you can introduce abstraction of it (interface or abstract class), implements that abstraction with Automapper methods.
With abstraction your application will not depend tightly on Automapper.

Comment: Just compare the complexity of such solution for hundreds of mappings with Automapper's single `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` call.

Comment: Does `AssertConfigurationIsValid()` works as you expected? For mapping with "deep object graph assertions" all tests can use only one "generic" test method, which will be executed for every possible mapping logic.

Comment: @IlyaChumakov, mapping from one type to another is part of your "business logic", where Automapper is implementation details of that logic. When you have automated tests of "business logic" you can freely play with Automapper configurations and you will always have "safe net" provided by tests. You can even change Automapper to another mapping framework and with small changes you can execute same tests against new framework.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is AutoMapper configuration validation, it does all the validations you point out. But instead of creating maps at runtime, simply create them up front (this has the added benefit of not accidentally creating invalid/incomplete/impossible maps).

Remove the `CreateMissingTypeMaps = true` part and create `Profile` types with explicit `CreateMap` calls to your types you want to map.

Comment: `CreateMap` means that anonimous types cann't be used, is it correct? The keypoint is to use them. Sorry for my late reply :(